# Bind JUnit test to a class

Tags: junit

I was wondering if there is a way where we can bind a JUnit test class (eg: `AbcTest`) to the class `Abc` such that whenever a method is added to `Abc`, either the same method stub is added to `AbcTest` or the test file shows an error. At times the additions are too many

Enjoy your Holidays!

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is to install [moreunit](http://moreunit.sourceforge.net/#documentation/missingtestmethodsview), which has a missing test methods views, where you can add any new methods to the test.

Comment: till something better is available, this works! A click much better than a hundred keystrokes. I'm trying it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You'd need a code generator to parse your class `Abc` and do the generation of `AbcTest` for you.

You can certainly do this to create empty method skeletons, but I'd question the value of doing so.  You still have to fill in the meat of the method; no generator will read your mind as to what an effective test would be.

And part of the value of writing the test - maybe the biggest benefit - is the thought you put into it.  A generator would destroy that aspect of unit testing.

Besides, if you're doing test-driven development, shouldn't you be writing the test *before* you write the method?  That'd be a Zen challenge for your generator....

Comment: not related to *test driven dev*. Methods are to be added to a class and having to write corresponding method stubs in the test class is both a pain and wastage of time. It would be nice if the stubs are created and I just flesh them out. The question is totally mechanical and about reducing manual effort on mundane tasks. I'm talking about a bit of automation here. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I get it.  A code generator is your automation.  Maybe your IDE has a plug-in or something that can help.  I still don't think it's a good idea.  I don't agree that the effort to generate those stubs is that great. But it's your choice.